# A build failure occurs when a maven project is running

Tags: maven, build-error

I'm using Maven 3.8.2 and I'm trying to run the project with mvn clean install command. But I get a build failure with following error message.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.552 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-18T12:01:36+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 92M/317M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M2:enforce (enforce-java-version) on project abcTest: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M2:enforce for parameter bannedRepositories: Cannot assign configuration entry 'bannedRepositories' with value 'http://*' of type java.lang.String to property of type java.util.List -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginConfigurationException
```

Can you help me to solve the above issue.

Comment: Please show the full pom file....

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is using an old version of maven-enforcer-plugin. This means you should upgrade to the [most recent version](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/).

The error message tells you that your configuration is wrong.

A configuration should look like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-repositories</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <bannedRepositories>
                  <bannedRepositories>
                    <bannedRepository>http://repo1/*<bannedRepository>
                  </bannedRepositories>
                  <bannedPluginRepositories>
                    <bannedPluginRepository>http://repo1/*<bannedPluginRepository>
                  </bannedPluginRepositories>
                                  
                  <!-- for some cases, white list is more effective -->
                  <!--
                                  
                  <allowedRepositories>
                    <allowedRepository>http://repo2/*<allowedRepository>
                  </allowedRepositories>
                  <allowedPluginRepositories>
                    <allowedPluginRepository>http://repo2/*<allowedPluginRepository>
                  </allowedPluginRepositories>
                                  
                  -->
                </bannedRepositories>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The full documentation can be found here:
https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedRepositories.html

Comment: And what exactly didn't work ?

Comment: It worked when I run the command(mvn clean install) in cmd as Administrator.